# Mutable strings in Python

Tags: python, string, mutable

Do you know of a Python library which provides mutable strings? Google returned surprisingly few results. The only usable library I found is http://code.google.com/p/gapbuffer/ which is in C but I would prefer it to be written in pure Python.

Edit: Thanks for the responses but I'm after an *efficient* library. That is, `''.join(list)` might work but I was hoping for something more optimized. Also, it has to support the usual stuff regular strings do, like regex and unicode.

Comment: Lists work pretty well for this purpose.

Comment: A couple of links: [LINK1](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-August/024485.html), [LINK2](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/)

Comment: Can you please explain, why do you need mutable strings? What is the use case?

Comment: @BasicWolf may be for memory-efficient replacements of chars inside the string? We're avoiding to create a copy of string.

Comment: @chuwy Well, there is a bytearray for those purposes. A string in Python is a-priori not a "memory-efficient" sequence, but rather concurrency-efficient. Consider this: you can always be sure, that no matter what a string modification operation on original string does not affect it. So, no problems in concurrency, thread safety etc.

Comment: @BasicWolf this would be appropriate addition to the top-voted answer.

Comment: Here's the truth mutable strings are used by working professionals, this is a trivial task in other languages and the only people who think immutable strings are a good idea are academics.  The fact you have to write a class that is more complex than a doing the same task in Assembly language tells you "something is not right."  If you have cases like multithreading then those can be handled as "special cases" but I have programmed multithread systems since my first job out of college 30 years ago and it was never an issue.

Answer (score 30):

In Python mutable sequence type is **bytearray** see [this link](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable)

Comment: I am not sure what @Marcin is referring to because bytearrays allows you to assign a new value to a slice of the bytearray.

Comment: @jonathanrocher Check edit history. Marcin pointed out an error, and it was corrected.

Comment: This should be the 'correct' answer. Too much messing about involved in the current top-voted.

Comment: `bytearray` as the name obviously suggests is an array of bytes. Strings are not sequences of bytes but rather sequences of groups of bytes. I.e. this is only true for ASCII strings, not true for unicode in general. -1.

Comment: not really helpful if you want to use, say, the regex lib on a mutable.  if you need mutable objects, switch your language to c++ or rust.   python really, really, falls down when it comes to memory handling and mutability for projects that are sensitive to this sort of thing (like cryptography)

Comment: Beware of multi-byte characters. Example: bytearray('aé'.encode('utf8'))
bytearray(b'a\xc3\xa9')

Comment: @ErikAronesty You'd be reimplementing all of the `str` API. Which is a road to madness since that API is _huge_, and might grow or change with every Python version. It's much easier to have a buffer that you can assign to, and an easy way to take out strings, process them, and put the result back in.

Answer (score 23):

This will allow you to efficiently change characters in a string. Although you can't change the string length.

```
>>> import ctypes

>>> a = 'abcdefghijklmn'
>>> mutable = ctypes.create_string_buffer(a)
>>> mutable[5:10] = ''.join( reversed(list(mutable[5:10].upper())) )
>>> a = mutable.value
>>> print `a, type(a)`
('abcdeJIHGFklmn', <type 'str'>)
```

Comment: **BE WARNED** that the buffer includes the terminator into its reported `len()`. **This will break slices with negative indices** unless you add an extra `-1` to each negative index. (For unicode buffers, it's `-1`, too, because `len` and slice indices for these types are in characters.)

Comment: Note: in python3 ctypes.create_string_buffer() takes bytes-type-argument as parameter, and ctypes.create_unicode_buffer() takes string-type-argument.

Answer (score 15):

```
class MutableString(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = list(data)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "".join(self.data)
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.data[index] = value
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) == slice:
            return "".join(self.data[index])
        return self.data[index]
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self.data[index]
    def __add__(self, other):
        self.data.extend(list(other))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

... 
and so on, and so forth.

You could also subclass StringIO, buffer, or bytearray.

Comment: To be able to use regex and string methods like `find` you need to subclass from `str` instead of `object`.

Comment: Correction: regex and `find` only work on the original string. Modifications made through `__setitem__`are disregarded. Is there a way to use regex on MutableStrings?

Comment: You can do `re.match(expression, repr(mutable_string))`

Comment: But then you could as well use a normal string. I want/need to take advantage of the mutability.

Comment: Too many functions to override. And you would have to check if there are any differences between the `str` API of the various Python versions.

Answer (score 4):

How about simply sub-classing `list` (the prime example for mutability in Python)?

```
class CharList(list):

    def __init__(self, s):
        list.__init__(self, s)

    @property
    def list(self):
        return list(self)

    @property
    def string(self):
        return "".join(self)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, int) and len(value) != 1:
            cls = type(self).__name__
            raise ValueError("attempt to assign sequence of size {} to {} item of size 1".format(len(value), cls))
        super(CharList, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.string

    def __repr__(self):
        cls = type(self).__name__
        return "{}(\'{}\')".format(cls, self.string)
```

This only joins the list back to a string if you want to print it or actively ask for the string representation.
Mutating and extending are trivial, and the user knows how to do it already since it's just a list.

Example usage:

```
s = "te_st"
c = CharList(s)
c[1:3] = "oa"
c += "er"
print c # prints "toaster"
print c.list # prints ['t', 'o', 'a', 's', 't', 'e', 'r']
```

The following is fixed, see update below.

> There's one (solvable) caveat: There's no check (yet) that each element is indeed a character. It will at least fail printing for everything but strings. However, those can be joined and may cause weird situations like this: [see code example below]

With the custom `__setitem__`, assigning a string of length != 1 to a CharList item will raise a `ValueError`. Everything else can still be freely assigned but will raise a `TypeError: sequence item n: expected string, X found` when printing, due to the `string.join()` operation. If that's not good enough, further checks can be added easily (potentially also to `__setslice__` or by switching the base class to `collections.Sequence` (performance might be different?!), cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32772786/655404))

```
s = "test"
c = CharList(s)
c[1] = "oa"
# with custom __setitem__ a ValueError is raised here!
# without custom __setitem__, we could go on:
c += "er"
print c # prints "toaster"
# this looks right until here, but:
print c.list # prints ['t', 'oa', 's', 't', 'e', 'r']
```

Answer (score 3):

The [FIFOStr](https://pypi.org/project/FIFOStr) package in pypi supports pattern matching and mutable strings.   This may or may not be exactly what is wanted but was created as part of a pattern parser for a serial port (the chars are added one char at a time from left or right - see docs).  It is derived from deque.

```py
from fifostr import FIFOStr

myString = FIFOStr("this is a test")
myString.head(4) == "this"  #true
myString[2] = 'u'
myString.head(4) == "thus"  #true
```

(full disclosure I'm the author of FIFOstr)

Answer (score 2):

Efficient mutable strings in Python are *arrays*.
PY3 Example for unicode string using `array.array` from standard library:

```
>>> ua = array.array('u', 'teststring12')
>>> ua[-2:] = array.array('u', '345')
>>> ua
array('u', 'teststring345')
>>> re.search('string.*', ua.tounicode()).group()
'string345'
```

`bytearray` is predefined for bytes and is more automatic regarding conversion and compatibility.

You can also consider `memoryview` / `buffer`, `numpy` arrays, `mmap` and `multiprocessing.shared_memory`  for certain cases.

Comment: `array` is "deprecated since 3.3 and will be removed in 4.0". I highly suspect that, having a fixed item size, it doesn't handle surrogate pairs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a getter:

```
original_string = "hey all"
def get_string():
    return original_string
```

So when you need it you just call it like this:

```
get_string().split()
```

Answer (score -3):

Just do this
`string = "big"`
`string = list(string)`
`string[0] = string[0].upper()`
`string = "".join(string)`
`print(string)`

'''OUTPUT'''
  > Big

Comment: OP points out in the question description that he's looking for something more efficient than `''.join(list)`. He's also asking specifically for a library which provides *mutable* strings in Python (or some other approach to attain it). – Please revise your answer and explain why doing it in this way is still worthwhile from your perspective. Also giving an explanation rather than *just do this* is much more helpful for future readers. See also the [contribution guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for reference.