# C to python code conversion

Tags: c, python-3.x

I'm doing code conversion form C to python... 
I have a char array and is used as a String buffer

```
 char str[25]; int i=0;

 str[i]='\0';
```

Here i will be taking different values and even str[i] also holds different values

I want the equivalent code in python... Like a string buffer, where i can store n edit string contents inside. I even tried using a list but it is not very efficient so is there any other way out?? 
Is there any string buffer thing in Python? If so how can i use it according to these?

Comment: `str[i] = '\0';` is not possible in python as strings are immutable object in Python. Also remmember `str` is a type in Python

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Ya i know that, so is there no other way??

Comment: "I even tried using a list but it is not very efficient" How did you determine this?

Comment: @Puneeth Mark suggested `bytearray` array I have no idea, search for  Read also [Mutable strings in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572624/mutable-strings-in-python)  look at `MutableString` class

Answer (score 1):

Use a `bytearray` to store a mutable list of byte data in Python:

```
s = bytearray(b'My string')
print(s)
s[3] = ord('f')  # bytes are data not characters, so get byte value
print(s)
print(s.decode('ascii')) # To display as string
```

Output:

```
bytearray(b'My string')
bytearray(b'My ftring')
My ftring
```

If you need to mutate Unicode string data, then `list` is the way to go:

```
s = list('My string')
s[3] = 'f'
print(''.join(s))
```

Output:

```
My ftring
```