# How can I change the string object inside a string object?

Tags: python, string, object, immutability

I'm trying to create a mutable string object by just subclassing str ([Unlike the answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572792/1795924)).

Here's my code so far:

```
class mstr(str):

    def __new__(self, s):

        self.s = list(s)
        return str.__new__(self, s)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.s[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):    
        self.s[index] = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ''.join(self.s) == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return ''.join(self.s) != other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return len(self.s) < len(other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return len(self.s) > len(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return len(self.s) <= len(other)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return len(self.s) >= len(other)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return ''.join(self.s) + other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return ''.join(self.s) * other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(''.join(self.s))

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self.s)

def main():

    s = mstr("Hello ")
    s[5] = " World!"
    print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

By just outputting this example, it's easy to be fooled by the __ str __ return value:

```
Hello World!
```

It's also easy to be fooled by the return value of __ add __ :

```
print(s + " Bloody madness!")
```

Output:

```
Hello World! Bloody madness!
```

But the immutable truth is revealed once we pass the mstr itself by the other argument of __ add __, as an example:

```
print(s + s)
```

Output:

```
Hello World!Hello
```

Removing all the extra methods:

```
class mstr(str):

    def __new__(self, s):

        self.s = list(s)
        return str.__new__(self, s)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):    
        self.s[index] = value
        self = ''.join(self.s) # Foolish attepmt.
```

Output of print(s) is just "Hello ".

So, how can I change the string object inside the string object? I mean, WHERE is the string **actual** and ***physical*** **content** stored in str or object or whatever? Wherever that is, I want to assign **there**.

Comment: If you could do that, `str` wouldn't be immutable.  What it means for `str` to be immutable is that you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a985b6455fde/Include/stringobject.h#l35):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1]; // This part. (Not actually one char.)

    /* ... */
} PyStringObject;
```

Unless you want to screw with the memory directly with ctypes or something, you can't get at it. If you *do* screw with it, weird things will break, because the assumption that that data is immutable isn't waived for string subclasses.