# How to get for loop in a function to return (not print) in single one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to rename text/num ids (eg. ABC123) to just num ids (eg. 123123) by matching text to a dictionary code. (just learning how to code, so if better idea, please do tell).

I tried searching for solutions but many are for using print. I need to pass the results to another function, so can't use print.

```
def convertid(old_id):
    code = {'A' : '1','B' : '2','C' : '3','D' : '4','E' : '5','F' : 
    '6','G' : '7','H' : '8','I' : '9','J' : '10','K' : '11','L' : 
    '12','M' : '13','N' : '14','O' : '15','P' : '16','Q' : '17','R' :        
    '18','S' : '19','T' : '20','U' : '21','V' : '22','W' : '23','X' : 
    '24','Y' : '25','Z' : '26', '1' : '1','2' : '2','3' : '3','4' : 
    '4','5' : '5','6' : '6','7' : '7','8' : '8','9' : '9','0' : '0'}

    for x in old_id:
        new_id = code[x],end = ""
        return new_id
```

I've also tried `new_id = "".join(code[x])`,and `new_id += code[x]`, but none of them work.

I was hoping to get "123123" as the new id in a single line, instead of:

1

2

3

1

2

3

on multiple lines (sorry, don't know why the preview is showing the numbers on double space lines. The result I got were in single space lines.).

Comment: The answer given is about as close as you can get. So, on another angle, you know that this transformation is irreversible, right? Letters and numbers are mapping to the same integer values.

Comment: Also, `"26"` could have either been `"Z"` or `"BF"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join on an empty string:

```
code = {'A' : '1','B' : '2','C' : '3','D' : '4','E' : '5','F' : 
    '6','G' : '7','H' : '8','I' : '9','J' : '10','K' : '11','L' : 
    '12','M' : '13','N' : '14','O' : '15','P' : '16','Q' : '17','R' :        
    '18','S' : '19','T' : '20','U' : '21','V' : '22','W' : '23','X' : 
    '24','Y' : '25','Z' : '26', '1' : '1','2' : '2','3' : '3','4' : 
    '4','5' : '5','6' : '6','7' : '7','8' : '8','9' : '9','0' : '0'}

i = 'A4BC'

n = "".join(code[l] for l in i)

print(n)

# 1423
```

Comment: `join` is one side case where the expression is slower than a list comprehension. `n = "".join([code[l] for l in i])` will be faster and is just as clean IMO

Comment: Really @roganjosh ? I didn't realize. Hopefully I'll have time to set up some timing tests later today. That's interesting, thank you

Comment: Yep, the whole list will still get expanded out prior to `join` doing any work. It's faster to use the list comp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `new_id += code[x]` like below

```
def convertid(old_id):
    code = {'A' : '1','B' : '2','C' : '3','D' : '4','E' : '5','F' : 
    '6','G' : '7','H' : '8','I' : '9','J' : '10','K' : '11','L' : 
    '12','M' : '13','N' : '14','O' : '15','P' : '16','Q' : '17','R' :        
    '18','S' : '19','T' : '20','U' : '21','V' : '22','W' : '23','X' : 
    '24','Y' : '25','Z' : '26', '1' : '1','2' : '2','3' : '3','4' : 
    '4','5' : '5','6' : '6','7' : '7','8' : '8','9' : '9','0' : '0'}

    new_id = ''
    for x in old_id:
        new_id += code[x]
    return new_id
print(convertid('ABC123')) # 123123
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008289/4799172 Don't concatenate strings in loops if you can use `join`

Comment: I just wanted to point out that it can be done with `new_id += code[x]` since OP explicitly mentioned they could not.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works too! I put the return under the wrong indentation, still learning!

Answer (score 1):

using `get` which will handle the case if `key` is not present and use default value`''` in that case

```
code = {'A' : '1','B' : '2','C' : '3','D' : '4','E' : '5','F' : 
        '6','G' : '7','H' : '8','I' : '9','J' : '10','K' : '11','L' : 
        '12','M' : '13','N' : '14','O' : '15','P' : '16','Q' : '17','R' :        
        '18','S' : '19','T' : '20','U' : '21','V' : '22','W' : '23','X' : 
        '24','Y' : '25','Z' : '26', '1' : '1','2' : '2','3' : '3','4' : 
        '4','5' : '5','6' : '6','7' : '7','8' : '8','9' : '9','0' : '0'}

i = 'A4BC'
print(''.join(code.get(l,'') for l in i))
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008289/4799172 Don't concatenate strings in loops, use `join`

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks this is interesting.

Comment: Next up is my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598296/how-to-get-for-loop-in-a-function-to-return-not-print-in-single-one-line#comment95993002_54598344). I'll try track down the link :)