# Space Complexity — Reassigning and returning parameter rather than create new variable to return

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm curious if to save on space, you can reassign the parameter and return that rather than creating a whole new string to return. Since it's local to the scope, I figure it shouldn't affect anything other than possibly make it a little more difficult to debug. Is it good practice or even a standard just to create a new variable and return it? Thanks.

E.g. creating and returning new_str:

```
def string_compression(string):
    new_str = ""

    dict = {}
    for char in string:
        if char not in dict:
            dict[char] = 1
        else:
            dict[char] += 1
    for key, value in dict.items():
        new_str += key + str(value)

    return new_str
```

Versus: (no new_str variable is created or returned)

```
def string_compression(string):
    dict = {}
    for char in string:
        if char not in dict:
            dict[char] = 1
        else:
            dict[char] += 1

    string = ""
    for key, value in dict.items():
        string += key + str(value)

    return string
```

Comment: Please, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008010/is-the-time-complexity-of-iterative-string-append-actually-on2-or-on 
You will see that your time is quadratic and you will learn how to reduce it to linear

Comment: The fact that you create a new variable is not really relevant here. In *both* versions, you create *a whole new string* (it would be anyway since you have to build that dictionary)

Comment: @Andrey OP is asking about space complexity, not time complexity, although you raise a good point.

Comment: @Dev please don't call a variable `dict`--it overwrites a builtin function. There's no difference between the two code snippets in terms of space _complexity_ (it's still `O(len(string))` either way), although the second is somewhat more optimal in the sense that it may let the garbage collector reclaim the parameter memory. However, this is a micro optimization that is almost entirely pointless to waste time thinking about. Just write clean code. Higher priorities are using `collections.Counter`, `defaultdict` `join` and avoiding the O(n^2) time complexity here.

Comment: How does using defaultdict reduce time complexity though? I've seen it used before, and it just seems to be implementing a function which does the same check behind the scenes, that I'm writing explicitly above when checking whether that key/value pair exists before modifying it somehow.

Comment: @Dev using `collections` doesn't improve the time complexity, although, likely the actual performance will be better, since various methods will be optimized in C.

Comment: @Dev the complexity will still be *O(n)*, but you should realise that *O(n)* is a fairly permissive requirement. A function that takes less than *n* hours to execute is said to be *O(n)*. A function that takes less than *n* milliseconds to execute is said to be *O(n)*. Using functions from the standard library will usually be faster than writing your own functions.

Comment: Even if it wasn't faster, it would be preferable because it makes your code easier to read. When I read `count_char = collections.Counter(txt)` I immediately understand that your are counting the occurrences of characters in string `txt`. But if instead, I have to read `count_char = {}; for c in txt: if c not in count_char: do_something else: do_something_else` then I have to read every one of those lines, take some time to understand what they do, then take some extra time to make sure they really do what I got the impression that they do.

Comment: How does appending to the string with each iteration make the time complexity O(n^2)? It is my understanding that there is no need to resize the string in place every iteration—only when the capacity of that string object in memory requires it to, as it is created in heap rather than the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To answer your question

In both code snippets, you are creating new strings. The fact that you give a different name to the string in the first version doesn't make it more or less efficient than the second version.

### An important remark about naming a variable `dict`

The name `dict` is the python name used for the builtin class for dictionaries. If you use that name for one of your own variables, even if it's a dictionary, you are running into a lot of trouble. You should avoid at all costs using builtin names for your own variables. Never call your variables `dict`, `list`, `str`, `sum`, or any name in that list: [Python Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). Instead, you can call your dictionary `d`, or `dictionary`, or better yet, something that explains what this dictinary is used for; for instance `char_count` or something similar.

### An important note about string concatenation

Consider the following code snippet:

```py
s = ''
for n in range(1000000):
  s += str(n)
```

It builds a string by concatenating numbers written in decimal: at the end, `s` is `'01234567891011...999997999998999999'`.

But is it efficient? No, it's not. The time complexity for concatenating two strings `s1` and `s2` using `+` or `+=` is proportional to the total number of characters in `s1` and `s2`. Here we are concatenating `''` with `'0'`, then `'0'` with `'1'`, then `'01'` with `'2'`, then `'012'` with `'3'`, then `'0123'` with `'4'`, etc. DO you see what is happening? This is the story of [Schlemiel the painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm). The complexity is quadratic instead of linear.

An more efficient way to concatenate more than two strings in python is to concatenate them all at once using `''.join(...)`. So instead we should write:

```py
s = ''.join(str(n) for n in range(1000000)).
```

### Using python module `collections`

Let's look at this code snippet:

```py
    d = {}
    for char in string:
        if char not in d:
            d[char] = 1
        else:
            d[char] += 1
```

Guess what? You're not the first one to have come across the need for this logic. If the value is not already in the dictionary, then add it; otherwise, update it. Four lines of code for such a mondaine operation! Surely we could automatize it a little more? Actually yes, we can. Instead of using a `dict`, we can use a `defaultdict`. The `defaultdict` will behave exactly like a `dict` would, but it will handle default values for us when needed:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for char in string:
  d[char] += 1
```

If `d[char]` doesn't exist when it's needed by `+=`, then the `defaultdict` will create it and give it the value returned by `int()`, which is 0. Everything works out exactly like before; except we don't have to write the `if`/`else` logic ourselves. Cool!

...But wait. Why did we need a dictionary in the first place? To count the number of occurrences of the characters in the string. This sounds like a common problem. In fact, it's so common that there is another subclass of `dict` even more suited than `defaultdict` for this! It's called `Counter` and it's also in module `collections`. You can replace the code above by:

```py
from collections import Counter

d = Counter(string)
```

and that's it. Yup. No need for a `for`-loop to fill the dictionary manually. It's all taken care of already.

### Useful reading

**Documentation**

- [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html);
- [module `collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html);
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join);

**StackOverflow question**

- [Is the time-complexity of iterative string append actually *O(n^2)*, or *O(n)*?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008199/3080723).

### Final code

```py
from collections import Counter

def string_compression(s):
  char_counts = Counter(s)
  return ''.join('{}{}'.format(c,n) for c,n in char_counts.most_common())

print(string_compression('aaaabcbcbb'))
# a4b4c2
```

If you want to keep the characters in their order of first appearance rather than sorted by decreasing count, you can replace `.most_common()` with `.items()` in the code.

Comment: In the case where an interviewer says I can't use the join method to build the string that is ultimately being returned, how would you suggest I build it using the key/value pairs like how I have in the example? Thanks Stef!

Comment: @Dev If I were in that position, I would look the interviewer in the eye, and explain to them, without losing my self-confidence, that python is the wrong language to refuse using `str.join`. I would offer to write a function in `C` to implement string concatenation manually. And I would point them to the python documentation page that specifically explains that in python, we should absolutely use `str.join` to perform string concatenation.

Comment: How would that function you'd write in C to implement string concatenation work, if it was to avoid O(n^2) from rebuilding the string through each iteration? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In python, strings are not mutable; so we're stuck with using functions the standard library offers to manipulate them. In C, by contrast, a string is an array of char and the programmer has all control on that array. You can allocate an array sufficiently large to hold the final result; copy the first string into the beginning of the array; copy the second string in the array after the last character of the first string; etc. Complexity of a single copying operation is proportional to the length of the string being copied. Total complexity is proportional to the total number of characters.

Comment: @Dev I would point you to CPython's implementation of `str.join`, but it might not be the easiest thing to read :p https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/join.h#L110

Comment: Yea, that's why I was hoping you knew a way in Python to write it! You have a very eloquent and succinct way of explaining for laymen such as myself :)

Comment: @Dev. Yes. collections.Counter is just a subclass of dict, so you can iterate over it just like you would iterate over a dict, using `.keys()`, `.values()` or `.items()`. In this case, just replace `.most_common()` with `.items()` to get what you want.

Comment: I had that Aha! moment literally right before you answered. Derp!

Answer (score 2):

The important term here is mutable, and nope, string are immutable objects, that is, you can't change their contents (try `string[0]='a'`).

Note there is no option at all to reassign an argument and affect the calling environment. There is no pass-by-reference (or pointers) as in other languages. Python uses what I think is called copy-by-reference. An object passes to a function by a copy of the reference to it from the caller (think address if you're coming from a pointer world), and everything in the function refers to that. You can change the original object, but reassign your argument and you lose your reference to it.

There is little chance this will affect space complexity in most cases.