# Time complexity- Big O for ''.join(sorted(a))

Tags: python-3.x, string, time-complexity, big-o

I want to know the time complexity of ''.join(sorted(a)) when done twice on 2 strings.

Comment: `sorted()` on its own `O(nlogn)` , see here for join https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008289/2308683

Comment: On two strings, `sorted` takes time at most proportional to the length of the shorter string, in order to do a lexicographic comparison. It's not clear what you mean by "done twice" though; after you've done it once, there is only one string.