# Random password generator only generating limited amount of characters

Tags: python, list, for-loop, password-generator

I am learning Python and today I decided to try and have a go at creating a random password generator. The code generates a random amount of letters, then numbers, then symbols, (based on the amount the user specifies). These values are all stored in a list where they are each concatenated with one another. From there the values are all re-randomized to produce a final password.

If I try to use large numbers as input (above around 40) it errors. It also doesn't always produce the specified length. If I input 30 letters, 30 numbers, and 30 symbols, for example, the final password is short of 90 by about 10 if I remember correctly. Any help would be appreciated--I think the fix is simple just having trouble finding it.

```
Here is my code: 


import random
import itertools

# lists
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
syms = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','+','_']

# inputs
print("Python Password Generator : \n")
charAmount = int(input("How many letters would you like to have in your password? : "))
numAmount = int(input("How many numbers? : "))
symAmount = int(input("How many symbols? : "))

# random num/sym/char

randomNum = ""
for num in nums :
  if int(num) < numAmount :
    randomNum += nums[random.randint(0,9)]


randomSym = ""
for sym in range(0, symAmount):
  if sym < symAmount :
    randomSym += syms[random.randint(0,9)]


randomChar = ""
for char in range(0, charAmount) :
  if sym < charAmount :
    randomChar += chars[random.randint(0, 25)]


# Final Password generator
generatorList = list(itertools.chain(randomNum,randomSym,randomChar))

Password = ""
tot = len(generatorList)
for word in generatorList:
      Password += generatorList[random.randint(0,tot)]

print(f"Your new password is : {Password}")
```

Comment: Your `for num in nums` loop can only give you 10 values due to the length of `nums`. Also, I think you can randomly select more efficiently using [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues with your code:

1. The `if` statements aren't necessary, because the number of iterations is limited by the `for` loop already.
2. `random.randint()` has inclusive arguments on both sides. So, in this code snippet:

```py
Password = ""
tot = len(generatorList)
for word in generatorList:
      Password += generatorList[random.randint(0,tot)]
```

`.randint()` can return `tot`, which is out of range for the `generatorList`.

Here is a code snippet that resolves both of these issues:

```py
import random
import itertools
# lists
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
syms = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','+','_']

# inputs
print("Python Password Generator : \n")
charAmount = int(input("How many letters would you like to have in your password? : "))
numAmount = int(input("How many numbers? : "))
symAmount = int(input("How many symbols? : "))

# random num/sym/char

randomNum = ""
for num in range(numAmount) :
    randomNum += nums[random.randint(0,9)]

randomSym = ""
for sym in range(0, symAmount):
    randomSym += syms[random.randint(0,9)]

randomChar = ""
for char in range(0, charAmount) :
    randomChar += chars[random.randint(0, 25)]

# Final Password generator
generatorList = list(itertools.chain(randomNum,randomSym,randomChar))

Password = ""
tot = len(generatorList)
for word in generatorList:
     Password += generatorList[random.randint(0,tot - 1)]

print(f"Your new password is : {Password}")
```

---

Those fix your immediate issues, but there's also a few extra improvements we could make:

1. Rather than list out the lowercase characters and digits, we can use constants from the `string` module.
2. [Repeated string concatenation is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34008010/17769815). Use `.join()` instead.
3. Use `random.choices()` to pick the characters to add to our password, then shuffle them all at the end.

With all this in mind, we get the following:

```py
import random
import string

chars = string.ascii_lowercase
nums = string.digits
syms = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','+','_']

print("Python Password Generator : \n")
char_amount = int(input("How many letters would you like to have in your password? : "))
num_amount = int(input("How many numbers? : "))
sym_amount = int(input("How many symbols? : "))

password_characters = random.choices(chars, k=char_amount) + random.choices(nums, k=num_amount) + random.choices(syms, k=sym_amount)
random.shuffle(password_characters)

password = ''.join(password_characters)
print(f"Your new password is : {password}")
```