# Pretty table layout to make title inside the dividing lines

Tags: python, layout, prettytable

I have the following code for pretty table which goes like this:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

myTable = PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Class", "Section", "Percentage"])
myTable.title = 'Big Bang Theory'
  
# Add rows
myTable.add_row(["Leanord", "X", "B", "91.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Penny", "X", "C", "63.5 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Howard", "X", "A", "90.23 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Bernadette", "X", "D", "92.7 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Sheldon", "X", "A", "98.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Raj", "X", "B", "88.1 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Amy", "X", "B", "95.0 %"])
print(myTable)
```

This produces the following table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|               Big Bang Theory               |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
| Student Name | Class | Section | Percentage |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
|   Leanord    |   X   |    B    |   91.2 %   |
|    Penny     |   X   |    C    |   63.5 %   |
|    Howard    |   X   |    A    |  90.23 %   |
|  Bernadette  |   X   |    D    |   92.7 %   |
|   Sheldon    |   X   |    A    |   98.2 %   |
|     Raj      |   X   |    B    |   88.1 %   |
|     Amy      |   X   |    B    |   95.0 %   |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

I was wondering if it possible for the following layout:

```
+--------------(Big Bang Theory)--------------+
| Student Name | Class | Section | Percentage |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
|   Leanord    |   X   |    B    |   91.2 %   |
|    Penny     |   X   |    C    |   63.5 %   |
|    Howard    |   X   |    A    |  90.23 %   |
|  Bernadette  |   X   |    D    |   92.7 %   |
|   Sheldon    |   X   |    A    |   98.2 %   |
|     Raj      |   X   |    B    |   88.1 %   |
|     Amy      |   X   |    B    |   95.0 %   |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Kindly please advise if such a layout is possible

### Edit 1

I added this:

```
table_txt = myTable.get_string()
```

[image]

```
table_txt = table_txt.replace("+---------------------------------------------+\n|               Big Bang Theory               |\n+--------------+-------+---------+------------+", "+--------------(Big Bang Theory)--------------+")

print(table_txt)
+--------------(Big Bang Theory)--------------+
| Student Name | Class | Section | Percentage |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
|   Leanord    |   X   |    B    |   91.2 %   |
|    Penny     |   X   |    C    |   63.5 %   |
|    Howard    |   X   |    A    |  90.23 %   |
|  Bernadette  |   X   |    D    |   92.7 %   |
|   Sheldon    |   X   |    A    |   98.2 %   |
|     Raj      |   X   |    B    |   88.1 %   |
|     Amy      |   X   |    B    |   95.0 %   |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

This approach assumes that table width is static thus if the width changes, the junction of the first line does not align with the rest of the table.

Comment: You can export the table in a string and do some custom formatting, based on table width and title lenght.

Comment: @Jakobヤコブ Do you mean something like this: `table_txt = myTable.get_string()` and `table_txt.replace("+---------------------------------------------+\n|               Big Bang Theory               |\n+--------------+-------+---------+------------+", "+--------------(Big Bang Theory)--------------+")`

Comment: Basically yes. But if you also want to use a different title it needs to be much more dynamic.

Comment: @Jakobヤコブ So title should be saved in a variable using regex to find center and overwrite character?

Comment: I will write a quick answer (comment is to small).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from prettytable import PrettyTable

myTable = PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Class", "Section", "Percentage"])
title = 'Big Bang Theory'
  
# Add rows
myTable.add_row(["Leanord", "X", "B", "91.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Penny", "X", "C", "63.5 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Howard", "X", "A", "90.23 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Bernadette", "X", "D", "92.7 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Sheldon", "X", "A", "98.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Raj", "X", "B", "88.1 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Amy", "X", "B", "95.0 %"])
for n, l in enumerate(myTable.get_string().split('\n')):
    if n == 0:
        l = f"+{f'({title})'.center(len(l)-2, '-')}+"
    print(l)
```

It is enumerating the lines of the table as a string and for the first line, center the title and replace it.

```
+--------------(Big Bang Theory)--------------+
| Student Name | Class | Section | Percentage |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
|   Leanord    |   X   |    B    |   91.2 %   |
|    Penny     |   X   |    C    |   63.5 %   |
|    Howard    |   X   |    A    |  90.23 %   |
|  Bernadette  |   X   |    D    |   92.7 %   |
|   Sheldon    |   X   |    A    |   98.2 %   |
|     Raj      |   X   |    B    |   88.1 %   |
|     Amy      |   X   |    B    |   95.0 %   |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Works for any width.

#### edit

Not sure if I understood your comment, but I think you mean to have the table as string and not print it, then do this

```
table_txt = ''
for n, l in enumerate(myTable.get_string().split('\n')):
    if n == 0:
        l = f"+{f'({title})'.center(len(l)-2, '-')}+"
    table_txt = f'{table_txt}{l}\n'
```

You may find other ways of concatenating strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572624/mutable-strings-in-python) but you should not have performance problems with these kind of tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Quick question, I am not able to print the table if I tab  `print(l)` left. `myTable.get_string()` is variable `table_txt` for me and the modification has to be saved on `table_txt`. Could you please advise!

Answer (score 1):

1. Export your table to a string, and keep the title in the variable as you already do.
2. Calculate the width of the table. This can easily be done by splitting the string at `\n` and getting the length of any string in the split array.
3. Remove the first 2 rows of the table. You can use `split` function or do some regex.
4. Write a function to build a string of `-` with a centered title based on table width.
5. Print the string.